# OKEX, API v5 , swap contracts, place order error :Parameter posSide error

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, cryptocurrency

I am trying to create a perpetual limit order using Okex.net. The API is successfully placing orders(both limit and market) on spot exchange but not on perpetual exchange.

API document : https://www.okex.com/docs-v5/en/#rest-api-trade-place-order

Here is what I am trying:

```
OkexClient api = new OkexClient();
api.SetApiCredentials("***", "***", "***");
var trade_01 = api.PlaceOrder("XLM-USDT-SWAP", OkexTradeMode.Cross, OkexOrderSide.Buy, OkexPositionSide.Long, OkexOrderType.MarketOrder, 300m);
```

Error Message:

```
{
      "code": "1",
      "data": [
        {
          "clOrdId": "",
          "ordId": "",
          "sCode": "51000",
          "sMsg": "Parameter posSide  error ",
          "tag": ""
        }
      ],
      "msg": ""
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this can affect behavior (I've read data with their API but not traded), but maybe check if your account is in long/short mode vs. net

https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#rest-api-account-set-position-mode

Comment: As @johnmcs suggests there are two modes and by default it is the long/short mode that is selected which means that for FUTURES and SWAP you need to the provide the "side" parameter (buy or sell) but also the "posSide" parameter which is long or short. Alternatively you can select the net mode which means that you only need to provide the "side" parameter. As the error suggests you are missing the posSide parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using OkexClient but this body worked for me. Maybe if you send parameteres like this it works.

```
{
  "instId" : "someSymbol-SWAP",
  "tdMode" : "isolated or cross",
  "clOrdId" : "someClientOrderId",
  "side" : "buy or sell",
  "ordType" : "limit or market",
  "sz" : "contract size like 1 or 2 etc..",
  "px": "somePrice"
}
```